# Select2 Page Up/Down List Scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery-select2

[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) eats the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> key events to prevent the page from scrolling, but I want the active list to scroll when these keys are pressed.

The challenge is scrolling the list by the correct number of indices, or pixels, if possible. Naively, I am calling `this.moveHighlight(-5);` on `KEY.PAGE_UP` and similar for `KEY.PAGE_DOWN`.

What is the correct way to scroll the Select2 dropdown by exactly one page?

Here is the code that swallows the events:

```
if (e.which === KEY.PAGE_UP || e.which === KEY.PAGE_DOWN) {
    // prevent the page from scrolling
    killEvent(e);
    return;
}
```

Comment: [The issue on Github](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1851)